# Flutterfire doesn't work with 'FirebaseError: Unable to parse JSON' error

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a flutter project and I wanted have push notification in this project, but when I wanted to init firebase_options.dart file, I got error like this :

I did this:
[image: Click]

And I got this back from 'firebase-debug.log':
[image: Click]

How can I solve this problem...

I wanted to have push notification services in my project but that service didn't work.
I tried any way but I couldn't.

Comment: Would it be possible to share the log as text instead of images?

Comment: I putted log as image!?... what d u mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when you have not logged in from firebase cli or have  your login session expired.

Follow the below steps:

1. Run `npm install -g firebase-tools` or `sudo npm install -g firebase-tools` (if you are on mac) in terminal
2. Run `firebase login --reauth` and login from your browser window by clicking the printed link in terminal.
3. Now run `flutterfire configure ...`

Note: Verify you login to firebase cli from the email account associated with your firebase project.

Comment: I did it, But it's same.

Comment: Okay, can you try running `firebase login --reauth` first and then `flutterfire configure ...` and tell me what happens?