# a problem with the flutterfire configure command

Tags: flutter, firebase, visual-studio-code

FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.

I'm trying to add Firebase to my Flutter app. I have followed the steps mentioned on the firebase console 'Add Firebase to your Flutter app'

- Install the Firebase CLI and log in (run firebase login)
- Install the Flutter SDK
- Create a Flutter project (run flutter create)

next, as mentioned in firebase console, run the command

- dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
  in firebase-tools.exe file. The following messages appeared in the output:
  "Package flutterfire_cli is currently active at version 0.2.7.
  The package flutterfire_cli is already activated at newest available version.
  To recompile executables, first run `dart pub global deactivate flutterfire_cli`.
  Installed executable flutterfire.
  Activated flutterfire_cli 0.2.7."

Then, at the root of my Flutter project directory, I run this command

- flutterfire configure --project=%myprojectname%
  as mentioned in instruction it should automatically registers my per-platform apps with Firebase and adds a lib/firebase_options.dart configuration file to my Flutter project. but the below comment is appeared
  "i Found 0 Firebase projects. Selecting project daneshjooyarp1.
  FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
  COMMAND: firebase --version
  ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it."
  and the firebase_options.dart isn't created.

when I run "firebase projects:list", my project list is recognized and listed correctly!

** I haven't NodeJs and "npm install -g firebase-tools" not work on m system

Comment: Are you on Mac? Why isn't the `npm install -g firebase-tools` command working?

Comment: No, I am on windows. I don't know 

Comment: Is the `firebase-tools` already installed? Are you able to use `firebase` command in terminal? If yes, how did you install the `firebase-tools` in the first place?

Comment: Yes, the project list, login, logout,...  command of firebase works properly. I did it with .exe file dowloaded from https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli. (https://firebase.tools/bin/win/instant/latest)

Comment: What is your node.js version? Can you try running the command `node -v`.

Comment: I haven't install node.js on my computer. I want to link my flutter project and firebase

Comment: Maybe thats why you can't install **firebase-tools** using `npm install -g firebase-tools` command.

Can you try [installing node.js](https://nodejs.org/en) first then try running `npm install -g firebase-tools`.

If it works try following steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76228980/15428718)

Comment: I follow your command. when I try to login to firebase, the error is occurred "Unable to fetch the CLI MOTD and remote config".  and my project list is not recognized longer and failed to load.